# Im getting "com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, db2

My code :

```
@Id
    @Column(name = "cust_admin_id" )
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Cust_Admin_seq" , sequenceName = "cust_Admin_id",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE , generator = "Cust_Admin_seq")
    private Integer custAdminId;
```

Please help as this is in production...

Answer (score 2):

you violate a constraint.

f.e. you insert the same dataset twice (same primary key, maybe different values) or you insert a dataset, that has no foreign key dataset connected to another table.

We need a bit more information